# Why wont my soft bodies collide with each other?

Tags: animation, physics, soft-body

I have 3 soft bodies in my scene that I am making. All 3 objects have collision and softbody on. I have a plane that they land on that also has collision turned on. The soft bodies collide with the plane, but not with each other. Self collision is also turned on for all of them.

Comment: soft bodies won't collide with each other. Just join them so that they are one mesh, then it works.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback! This really helped.

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soft bodies won't collide with each other. Just join them so that they are one mesh, then they will collide with "each other" - although they are one mesh now ;)